# JSON won't compile, gives: "Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '['" error

Tags: json, pebble-sdk

Can someone please tell me whats wong with this code? Ive tried everything and don't know why it keeps giving me this error:

Parse error on line 3:
...",    "shortName": “Simple”,    "longN

----------------------------------------------^

Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '['

```
{
    "uuid": "13371337-d579-4d75-a5c5-8dfcfe110f62",
    "shortName": “Simple”,
    "longName": “Simple”,
    "companyName": “pjtnt11”,
    "versionCode": 1,
    "versionLabel": “1.7”,
    "watchapp": 
        {
            "watchface": true
        },
    "appKeys": 
        {
            "dummy": 0
        },
    "resources": 
        {
            "media": []
        }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: the quotes look suspicious, like microsoft-added typesetters quotes.  Make sure youre using the straight quotes (like youre using everwhere else)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're using “ instead of " for many of your strings. Those may not look like different double-quote characters, but they are. Only the latter is valid in JSON.

This usually happens to me when pasting quotation marks from another program, especially office software that likes to make its quotes look as fancy as possible.

The corrected JSON would be:

```
{
    "uuid": "13371337-d579-4d75-a5c5-8dfcfe110f62",
    "shortName": "Simple",
    "longName": "Simple",
    "companyName": "pjtnt11",
    "versionCode": 1,
    "versionLabel": "1.7",
    "watchapp": {
        "watchface": true
    },
    "appKeys": {
        "dummy": 0
    },
    "resources": {
        "media": [

        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: bro.i am ios developer. i want to ask is this backend side issue? our our side/

Answer (score 0):

Use the following `json`:

```js
{
    "uuid": "13371337-d579-4d75-a5c5-8dfcfe110f62",
    "shortName": "Simple",
    "longName": "Simple",
    "companyName": "pjtnt11",
    "versionCode": 1,
    "versionLabel": "1.7",
    "watchapp": 
        {
            "watchface": true
        },
    "appKeys": 
        {
            "dummy": 0
        },
    "resources": 
        {
            "media": []
        }
}
```

The issue is your values not using correct quotation marks