# Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid escape sequence around character 746."

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, nsjsonserialization

I am getting this error

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid escape sequence around character 746." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid escape sequence around character 746.}

Here is my code to parse JSON:

```
NSString *strResponse = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
strResponse=[self stringByRemovingControlCharacters:strResponse];
NSData *jsonData =  [strResponse dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
responseObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&serializationError
```

Using this code I am getting response object in other API.
but in my API contains HTML tags.

My issue is I am getting JSON string but it is not parsing in JSON.
for this API I am getting error

> "Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840".

My conclusion is that JSON is not parsing properly in above code.

Comment: @iYoung that is me.in that question i did not add any code.so i ask separate questio

Comment: Then why this separate question you must have updated that question.

Comment: I think your API doesn't return valid JSON or maybe some error in backend .. better to contact your backend developer

Comment: This is not at all a good practise to ask same question as 2 different question. You must edit your main question to add details. If you think you are not getting much attention try to give bounty to that question.

Comment: @iYoung Ok.from next time i will update question

Comment: @KrutarthPatel I would suggest do that this time as well delete either of your question as this is not a good impression.

Comment: @EICaptainv2.0 this response is working in android side.

Comment: @iYoung i deleted last question

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for getting my point.

Comment: Post your **strResponse** value

Comment: @Wolverine when i add response in json viewer.error showing in html string.and when i parse that html string in html viewer it is showing. but it is also showing \n\n.

Comment: can you please log **strResponse** value and add to question, By which we can see what things you should remove. Other wise no one's will able to help you...

Comment: @KrutarthPatel Kindly add value of strResponse which you are parsing so that we can get to know where it is getting wrong.

Comment: @iYoung i will add in 10 minutes.

Comment: @iYoung sorry i can't share response.but when i paste response in jsonlint.i am getting error at html value ."Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '[', got 'undefined'
"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28014855/json-wont-compile-gives-expecting-string-number-null-true-false

Comment: @iYoung can you check this question. so at least we can get conclusion.error is from backend or my side

Comment: unless you show the *strResponse* we cannot completely say that its a backend problem. so update the question and provide the *strResponse*

Comment: @KrutarthPatel I think you responce not json formatter some html tag available so the parser show error. You can change your serialisation method to `AFHTTPResponseSerializer`. I hope its helpful to you. Thanks

Comment: @ilesh i change. 
   self.requestSerializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];
    self.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
right?

Comment: and also change the accept content type `html/text`

Answer (score 0):

The string from Ur backend may be invalid JSON，it may contain "\s""\n""\t" or other tab character。And in Xcode u print it will not see the tab character,the console will not print them.You may get the JSON and find if there are tab characters.

Answer (score 0):

NSJSONSerialization throw an error if you try to escape ” character using \”. Only " need to be escaped